# Double Quote not close Java

Tags: java, csv, double-quotes, csvreader

J have CSV File first row is like this :

LOC;11000;"Autorisation "valide";10;;

When i try to read it with CSVReader i have only this:

LOC;11000

I know the problem is the double quote, how i can do to remove all double quote on my CSV ?

I try replace method is dosnt work.

My code is:

```
while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {

    for(int i = 0; i<line.length; i++) {

        if (line[i].contains("\"")){

            line[i] = line[i].replace("\"", ""); // same result with replaceAll method
        }

        System.out.print(line[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're only trying to replace the quotes if there is a "\n" in the entry at index i, which (as shown by your CSV example) does not contain any quotations. To put it another way, you are trying to do something like "\n".replace("\"","") which effectively does nothing.

Comment: i mean if (line[i].contains("\""))

Comment: yes is a array : String line[]; i cant do line = line.replace("\"", "");

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Brendan, the line " if (line[i].contains(""")){" is redundant. The find and replace method will scan the text anyways, you don't need to do it twice.

Your replace statements works, I tried it, but that is not the issue:

```
jshell> var text = "LOC;11000;\"Autorisation \"valide\";10;;";
text ==> "LOC;11000;\"Autorisation \"valide\";10;;"

jshell> text.contains("\"")
$2 ==> true

jshell> text.replace("\"","");
$3 ==> "LOC;11000;Autorisation valide;10;;"
```

Notice that line is not a list/iteratable, its a string, so you can just  replace it on line.

```
while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
     line = line.replaceAll("[\"\\\\]","");  
     System.out.print(line);
}
```

[image]

Comment: i dont have var text = "LOC;11000;\"Autorisation \"valide\";10;;"; but i have  var text = "LOC;11000;\"Autorisation "valide\";10;;";

Comment: I'm assuming from the csvreader tag that the readNext method is from CSVReader [reader.readNext()](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html#readNext--) which has a method signature of `public String[] readNext() throws IOException, CsvValidationException`.

Comment: I updated it with a regex replace to work for that condition as well, @maa_amm. Good luck with your project.